# is recursion the solution ?- Python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to find out which words can be spelled using the Mendeelev table. For example, the word "helico" can be spelled as He Li C O (helium-lithium-carbon-oxygen), but also as He Li Co  (helium-lithium-cobalt). 
I wrote a small program to do this. I have words in word_list ("helico", "cute" and so on), and the elements are in elements ("H He Li"...)
I used a recursion, because I though I could take a word, look for an element at the beginning of the word, remove it, then restart the procedure with the shorter word. If the word ends up empty, it means it is spellable.
It works, but the issue is that once I have found a first solution (He Li C O), I find it difficult to get back to the next solution - He Li Co
Because of the recursivity, "helico" has become "co" and I will find Co, but have "forgotten" the first part (He Li)

My feeling is that because there are potentially several solutions for each word, recursion is not suited.

Any thoughts? I am not looking for THE solution, rather for the thinking to help me with this...

```py
def search_element(startword, match):
    print startword," MATCH IS",match
    if startword =="":
        print match, "empty startword"
        match =""
    for elem in elements:
        #print elem,
        if elem == "$$":
            match =""
        if startword.startswith(elem):
            newword = startword.replace(elem,"",1)
            match = match +" "+ elem
            #print startword, elem, match, "----", newword
            match = search_element(newword, match)
    return(match)


elements = ['h', 'he', 'li', 'be', 'b', 'c', 'n', 'o', 'f', 'ne', 'na', 'mg', 'al', 'si', 'p', 's', 'cl', 'ar', 'k', 'ca', 'sc', 'ti', 'v', 'cr', 'mn', 'fe', 'co', 'ni', 'cu', 'zn', 'ga', 'ge', 'as', 'se', 'br', 'kr', 'rb', 'sr', 'y', 'zr', 'nb', 'mo', 'tc', 'ru', 'rh', 'pd', 'ag', 'cd', 'in', 'sn', 'sb', 'te', 'i', 'xe', 'cs', 'ba', 'la', 'ce', 'pr', 'nd', 'pm', 'sm', 'eu', 'gd', 'tb', 'dy', 'ho', 'er', 'tm', 'yb', 'lu', 'hf', 'ta', 'w', 're', 'os', 'ir', 'pt', 'au', 'hg', 'tl', 'pb', 'bi', 'po', 'at', 'rn', 'fr', 'ra', 'ac', 'th', 'pa', 'u', 'np', 'pu', 'am', 'cm', 'bk', 'cf', 'es', 'fm', 'md', 'no', 'lr', 'rf', 'db', 'sg', 'bh', 'hs', 'mt', 'ds', 'rg', 'cp', 'uut', 'uuq', 'uup', 'uuh', 'uus', 'uuo', '$$']
word_list =['helico', 'cute']


for word in word_list:
    match=""
    search_element(word, match)
```

Comment: Hint: try grouping your elements by the length of the elements, from smallest to largest.

Comment: Prolog tail-recursion could work. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical case for recursion. Here's an example code:

```
def findall(word, elements):
    def sub(word, res):
        if word:
            for elt in elements:
                if word.startswith(elt):
                    yield from sub(word[len(elt):], res+[elt])
        else:
            yield res
    yield from sub(word, [])
```

Testing:

```
for word in word_list:
    for res in findall(word, elements):
        print(word, res)
```

yields

```
helico ['he', 'li', 'c', 'o']
helico ['he', 'li', 'co']
cute ['c', 'u', 'te']
cute ['cu', 'te']
```

Comment: Wow. Now I need to read up on "yield" - did not even know it existed!

Comment: @Thomas_r Please be aware that `yield from` is only available as of Python 3.3. If you happen to use an earlier version, please add that information to this (and any further) questions.

Comment: I did translate it to Python 2.7, using a for loop such as for el in sub(word[len(elt):], res+[elt]):
                        yield el .... still need to understand it... Many thanks for your elegant solution. Looks good.

Comment: Correct, that's the way to go for earlier versions of Python. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

I think that recursion is well suited to this problem. Let's put the Uu* elements aside for the moment, so that we have chunks of one and two letters. The number of possible arrangements grows exponentially with the length of a word. You have less than 100 possibilities wir 10-letter words, but more than 10,000 for 20-letter words.

But: You don't have to consider all of these possibilities. If you use recursion, you can avoid going down dead branches. So let's say that you want to return a list of combinations.

- Start with the original word `w`
- Is the word empty: Then we've found a string.
- Is the first letter a valid element symbol? save `w[1:]` and recurse with `w[1:]`
- Are the first two letters a valid element symbol? save `w[2:]` and recurse with `w[2:]`
- return the combined results one level up

Of course you will have to come up with a way to store the results so far. You could for example build a string with hyphens with each recursion and return a list conaining just that string when recursion hits an empty word.

That is much better than generating all combos and then checking whether they are valid elements. My example implementation splits a dictionary of about 50,000 words in less than half a second.

By the way, you should use a set or a dictionary instead of a list to store the element symbols.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. A couple of questions: Why should I use the lenght of the elements? When using startswith(elem), the lenght become irrelevant. The problem is climbing back from a "live" branch to the next "live" branch. When using recursion, the "trunk" below the live branch is lost. Also, why should I use a set or a dictionary instead of a list? many thanks

Comment: Barring the few Uu* elements, you have only one- and two-letter symbols to pick from. It is easier to code this special case than to cater for symbols of arbitrary lengths. Sets and dictionaries are unordered, but designed for fast look-up. You don't need the order of the elements here, you only need to know whether there is an element with a gven symbol. (Time difference isn't crucial, however. My example takes more than twice as much time with a list, but still runs fast enough, I think.)

Comment: Well, @usepa has just answered your question how to keep track of the solutions. (Very elegant. Yielding didn't occur to me. I've solved it by adding to a local list and passing that up to the original caller.)